# uploading files with curl and report http error

Tags: javascript

Helo,

I have made a simple page with html which has a button for choosing a file from my pc and enables to upload it.

```
     <div>
         <input  type="submit" name="my_file" id="my-file"></input>
    </div>
```

I want it to be able to upload a special file and in case the user upload a wrong file it will report http error (402). I have done it with curl post, like this:

```
    curl -i -F file=@my.license
```

According to:http://ariejan.net/2010/06/07/uploading-files-with-curl/ 
So here the uploaded file will be posted to the backend and if the file was ok it will be uploaded otherwise it sends the error.Now my question is that how can I produce this 402 http error from backend? Is it something server side that runs automaticall or I should make this error activated when the file is not correct?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, after uploading the file the server will validate the file and if the file is ok respond with a 200 OK or if the file is not valid then send the 402 response.

Your script will have to write the header to the output. Without knowing what you are running on the server I can't offer much more. The following assumes PHP:

If you are uploading the file to a php script, then php has

```
void header ( string $string [, bool $replace = true [, int $http_response_code ]] )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

eg. `header('HTTP/1.1 402 Payment Required');`

Are you sure that a 402 is what you want? [W3](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) has a list of HTTP status codes, maybe have a look through there as well.

Also please tag with the appropriate tag(s).

Answer (score 0):

Uploading a file to be validated on the server side should be a fallback option. You can validated the file before sending it. You can even disable file types.

To allow only certain file to be selected:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*"  type="submit" name="my_file" id="my-file" />
```

That example will allow only images to be selectable in the file open dialog. For a list of content-types (mime-types): http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types

You can also use the [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/FileList) and [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/File) to check the file type as well. See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Y6MjA/4/

```
var file = document.getElementById('my-file').files[0];
switch(file.type)
{
    case 'image/png':
    case 'image/gif':
    case 'image/jpeg':
        alert('Valid File Type');
        //success: upload your file via curl
        break;
    default:
        alert('Invalid File Type');
}
```